# script to detect alwayson redo latency in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, availability-groups

I have 2 node SQL 2019 AlwaysON setup where i regularly see latency for redo thread in AG dashboard when applying the redo transactions on secondary. we have identified that this redo thread delay in applying is becasue of a high reporting workload on secondary. My requirement is to kill the reporting 'Select' query on secondary if it is affecting redo thread for more than 5mins. Is there a way to achieve this solution? any blogs/scripts available. Kindly help.

Thanks for assistance.

Comment: Have you look at your reporting queries to see if you cannot  simply "tune" them or create indexes that would reduce this workload? That would fix the issue.
Killing session usually end up with end user simply re-launching their query right after you killed them

Comment: thanks. yes we are in process of tuning the reporting queries as well. i was looking for a script which can kill the reporting query if it is affecting redo thread for may be 5mins.

Comment: You can eventually set the secondaries in not readable mode, and then set them back to readable when the redo queue is no longer lagging.

Comment: is there a way to auto-kill the reporting queries on readable secondary without changing to non readable mode?